# Can a remote webpage loaded in Phonegap hybrid iOS app save data to iOS filesystem?

Tags: ios, cordova

We have a mobile web app hosted on a server. We want to convert it into a hybrid app using Phonegap, but we do not want to embed the html and other code in the www folder in the hybrid app. We want the pages to remain remote so that updating them can be independent of the app. This is an internal iOS app and we are not planning on submitting it to Apple.

This mobile web app makes some webservice calls which return back some json response. In the hybrid app, we want to save the json response on the iOS device filesystem. I know if we would embed the web app in the www folder of hybrid app, we can easily do so using plugins. But since the web app is remotely hosted, will it still be possible for phonegap plugins to talk to the javascript code and get the webservice response and save to the device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the **File** plugin to write, read, delete, upload and download files.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Example code for communicating with the plugin from your HTML in JS:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.write("some sample text");
}
```

For communicating with a web service from your app, you will have to update your **config.xml** with `<access origin="*" />`. jQuery Ajax works well for retrieving JSONs.